# Resuming Cancelled Download with WGET

Tags: download, wget

Half-way through a 4GB download I accidentally rebooted the system. Upon loading back up, I had the sheer horror of realising I cancelled the bloody download because of it. I've booted my Ubuntu VM and trying to WGET the rest of the file. According to [this](http://www.supermind.org/blog/844/resume-cancelledcrashed-downloads-in-google-chrome-on-ubuntuosx) blog post it is relatively easy.

I've exported my proxy server address to the http_proxy environment variable and I can successfully view webpages in FireFox. It's just unfortunate that I now receive the error:

`Resolving proxy.com... 16.236.18.243
Connecting to proxy.com|16.236.18.243|:80... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2012-01-19 04:53:28 ERROR 404: Not Found.`

From:

`wget --continue http://download.com/iso.iso`

I assumed it was a timeout issue so extended it to 60 seconds however this only resulted in a .txt file with the same error message on my desktop. I'm out of any options I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the wgetrc file.

More details [here](http://linuxers.org/tutorial/wget-proxy-how-run-wget-behind-proxy-server)